# String equals only part of a string

Tags: java, arrays, foreach

Im writing a code to make a new word (c) from user input (a & b), So i need a code to check if a string is equals to another, but it is showing that the string equals to only a part of another string.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GabungKata_1402019129 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("----------------------------------");
    System.out.println("    Program Gabung Kata");
    System.out.println("    Dibuat oleh 1402019129");
    System.out.println("----------------------------------");       

    System.out.print("Masukkan kata pertama: "); // Enter First word
    String first = sc.nextLine();                // Bbxx
    System.out.print("Masukkan kata kedua  : "); // Enter Second word
    String second = sc.nextLine();               // oxxx

    String result = ""; // new String that is a combination from first and 
                        // second                           
    String[] names = {"Bob", "Zidan", "Fawzan", "Arkan", "Raihan"};
    boolean data = true;
    int n = 0;

    do {


        for (String check: names) {      

            if (result.equals(check)) {
                data = false;
            }else
                data = true;
        }

        result += first.charAt(n);
        result += second.charAt(n);
        n++;            

    } while(data & n < first.length() & n < second.length());

    System.out.println("New Word: " + result);
    System.out.println("Is the new word is one of the names? " + !data);

 }
}
```

New word will display: "Bobxxxxx", but i think it is supposed to stop when result is equal to "Bob". What i need is a block of code to stop the loop when result is equal to one of the names. Im not good at english so i hope you guys can understand.

Comment: Please show the full code I counted at least four unknown variables.

Comment: `data` - which is a bad name for a flag - is always being set to `false`, because your `result` is not equal to `Lulu`, and it always continues through the list to `Lulu`. So as soon as you have one pair in `result`, `data` is false and the loop ends. But you display `!data` instead of `data`, so you think it found equality. The whole logic here is faulty. Please rethink your algorithm.

Comment: ok i will upload and change some code, i didnt because it's written in Indonesia.

Comment: What i need is "something" to stop the loop when 'result' is equals to one of the 'names' array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description, this should work, though I'm sure there are better ways to do this:

```
class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("----------------------------------");
        System.out.println("    Program Gabung Kata");
        System.out.println("    Dibuat oleh 1402019129");
        System.out.println("----------------------------------");

        System.out.print("Enter First word: "); // Enter First word
        String firstString = sc.nextLine();                // Bbxx
        System.out.print("Enter Second word  : "); // Enter Second word
        String secondString = sc.nextLine();               // oxxx

        String combinedString = ""; // new String that is a combination from first and
        // second
        String[] targetNames = {"Bob", "Zidan", "Fawzan", "Arkan", "Raihan"};
        boolean shouldContinue = true;
        int index = 0;

        String interlacedString = createInterlacedString(firstString, secondString);
        do {
            for (String targetName: targetNames) {

                if (combinedString.equals(targetName)) {
                    shouldContinue = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(shouldContinue){
                combinedString += interlacedString.charAt(index);
                index++;
            }
        } while(shouldContinue
                && (index < firstString.length())
                && (index < secondString.length())
        );

        System.out.println("New Word: " + combinedString);
        System.out.println("Is the new word is one of the names? " + !shouldContinue);

    }

    public static String createInterlacedString(String stringOne, String stringTwo){
        String interlacedString = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < stringOne.length(); i++){
            interlacedString += stringOne.charAt(i);
            if(i < stringTwo.length()){
                interlacedString += stringTwo.charAt(i);
            }
        }
        if(stringTwo.length() > stringOne.length()){
            interlacedString += stringTwo.substring(stringOne.length());
        }
        return interlacedString;
    }
}
```

Please note that the static class for createInterlacedString is just so I can run this in a scratch file in my IDE.

Comment: Thank you so much man, you really helped, i hope you have a great week.